# Quartz standalone client running job twice in Weblogic Server start up

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have taken a simple standalone client example from examples provided in quartz 1.6 download bundle to run a job. But at the start up of the weblogic server, job is running twice. Is there any settings or something required to run the job only once at the start-up of the server? If any code snippet or external link will be much helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue in tomcat. In my case I had my application bound to root path and to /appName path. So for instance there was app1.jar which was bound to / and to /app1 paths. As a result app was initialized twice in the server and hence quartz was triggered twice.

Comment: Hi Marcin Michalski, how you able to resolve this issue then?? any configuration settings you did??

Comment: I have stopped /app1 via tomcat manager and left only / (root) application running